# Slider state change with viewModel

Tags: slider, android-jetpack-compose, viewmodel

I would like to use slider value as input to a function, and output of that function to be input to a graph on the same screen. I understand that unidirectional data flow is the recommended architecture: e.g. define slider value in viewModel, pass to slider UI, pass modified value to viewModel function, return function output to UI. The function has been simplified for illustration purposes.

I am struggling to define slider values in the right way and the below code throws an error at onValueChange. I have tried deining onValueChange = it, but again, throws an error.

````
class COGViewModel: ViewModel() {

    var sliderP1 by mutableStateOf(0f)
    var cog by mutableStateOf(0f)

    fun calcs() {
        cog = sliderP1*-1
    }


@Composable
fun ScreenSetup(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    viewModel: COGViewModel = viewModel(),
){

MainScreen(
    sliderP1 = viewModel.sliderP1,
    cog = viewModel.cog
)
}

@Composable
// builds UI
fun MainScreen(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    sliderP1: Float,
    cog: Float

)

{
    Column(modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .padding(20.dp)
    ) {

        Slider(
            value = sliderP1,
            onValueChange = { sliderValue_ ->
                sliderP1 = sliderValue_
            },
            onValueChangeFinished = {
                // this is called when the user completed selecting the value
                Log.d("MainActivity", "sliderValue = $sliderP1"
                    )
            },
            valueRange = 0f..10f
        )

        Text(text = sliderP1.toString())
        Text(text = cog.toString())

    }




} ```
````

Comment: "the below code throws an error at onValueChange", Include the error in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a lambda to update your sliderP1 when you move slider.

```
@Composable
// builds UI
fun MainScreen(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    sliderP1: Float,
    onValueChange: (Float) -> Unit,
    onValueChangeFinished: () -> Unit
) {
    Column(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(20.dp)
    ) {

        Slider(
            value = sliderP1,
            onValueChange = onValueChange,
            onValueChangeFinished = onValueChangeFinished,
            valueRange = 0f..10f
        )

        Text(text = sliderP1.toString())
    }
}
```

And update ViewModel values or call value change finish like this

```
@Composable
fun ScreenSetup(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    viewModel: COGViewModel = viewModel(),
){

    MainScreen(
        sliderP1 = viewModel.sliderP1,
        onValueChange = {
            viewModel.sliderP1 = it
        },
        onValueChangeFinished = {
            // Do something
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: `class COGViewModel: ViewModel() {
var sliderP1 by mutableStateOf(0f)
var cog by mutableStateOf(0f)
fun calcs(cog: Float): Float {
cog = sliderP1*-1
return cog
}}`

Here is my viewModel: but in the MainActivity:

`MainScreen(
calcs = {viewModel.calcs()}` and `fun MainScreen(calcs: Float, cog: Float)`

I get an error 'value cog cannot be re-assigned' in my viewModel'... is this because of an incorrect lambda?

Comment: I used you ViewModel without any change for testing and it works as `var cog by mutableStateOf(0f)
`

Comment: So you did not receive an error at ` cog =sliderP1*-1`? The assignment error for me was within the function